# deleting a word starting with a specific letter/character php

Tags: php, regex

here is a simple example:

```
$correction = "game";
$text ="Hello this is an example of a $word that starts with a $dollar sign";
$text = str_replace("\$word",$correct,$text);
```

if I echo $text it will say : hello this is an example of a game that starts with a dollar sign. that works just fine.
Now I want to be able to change any word that starts with a dollar sign into game 
so it will change all the words that start with $ and turn them into the word "game"
any ideas please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a regex for this:

```
$text = preg_replace( '/\$[a-z]+/i', 'game', $text);
```

Comment: Careful on the end-of-line `$`--got me too on the first pass! :^)

Answer (score 5):

A simple regex should do the trick:

```
$text = preg_replace("#\$[^\b\s]+#", $correction, $text);
```

Comment: You probably want `[^\b]+`, no?

Comment: I might be wrong on that... Now [it matches everything](http://regexr.com?31loj). But without `+`, it doesn't match enough. Also, I believe this will match "non-words", right? Like if the string had `$4` in it or something like that.

Comment: Here is a working regex using word boundaries: `\$[^\b]+?\b` - Same downside of matching `$4`.

Comment: Yes--I assumed that was @fogsy's intention? Added `\s` to fix your test case.

Comment: Could be? Not sure. But adding `\s` will make it match `$test.ing`... Morale of the story: OP needs better requirements! :)

Comment: As well as the usual cautionary tale for anyone trying to write good regex's!

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression and preg_replace

```
$correction = "game";
$text ="Hello this is an example of a \$word that starts with a \$dollar sign";
$text = preg_replace('/\$\w+/', $correction, $text);
print $text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like so:

```
preg_replace("/(\w*)$([a-z]+)/i", "$1$correction", $text);
```

Note: I haven't tried it so my regex may be slightly flawed.